# React Native node_modules folder size

Tags: npm, react-native, npm-install, npmjs

After running:

```
react-native init FirstProject
```

I got **node_modules** folder with tons of modules and folder weighing about 139 MB.

Is it ok? Will it affect final application size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly ok. Unnecessary modules will be stripped at the time of deployment/testing on device/emulator. You can check your app size to be sure.